# Why do values not conflict when a thread runs the same method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Look here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test p = new test();

    new Thread(() => p.SayHello("Thread One")).Start();
    new Thread(() => p.SayHello("Thread Two")).Start();
}
```

then:

```
class test
{
    public void SayHello(string data)
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + data);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does second thread not reset the variable `i` to 0? and mess up the while loop which it is running on the first thread?

Comment: It's no different to calling these methods synchronously. As a thread (any thread) enters the method, local variables are only available within the method. If they are hoisted out of the method, then it becomes a different story..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `int i` is a local variable.  If you made it static to the class, rather than an local variable, it would be reset.  The variable is isolated to each thread in this case.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test p = new test();

    new Thread(() => p.SayHello("Thread One")).Start();
    new Thread(() => p.SayHello("Thread Two")).Start();
}

public class test
{
    static int i = 0;
    public static void SayHello(string data)
    {
        i = 0;

        while (i < 50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + data);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first sentence is correct here - but then you start talking about instance variables, which is a bit confusing when there aren't any... and if `i` *were* an instance variable, it would be problematic as there's only one instance.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, I fixed it.  Is that more accurate?

Comment: An instance member would have the same problem in this case.

Answer (score 5):

`i` is a local variable, so each thread has its own copy of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as each thread getting it's own "copy" of the SayHello method with it's local variables. If you wanted both threads to use the same i, you'd have to pass it by reference, and then the fun would start.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "by ref" ?

Comment: `int` is passed by value, so you would have to explicitly specify `ref` in order to get this to happen.